# JQuery Datable Select2 Multifilter with SQL Server

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, laravel, datatable

I have tried to make JQuery Datatables multiselect filters with select2 according to documentation but unfortunately regex is not natively supported in SQL server and I am getting

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.

This is MySQL working solution:

```
<select id="filter1" data-column="0" data-column_name="filter1_column" class="form-check-input filter-select" multiple>

        @foreach($values as $val)
            <option value="{{$val}}">{{$val}}</option>
        @endforeach

</select>
      var table = $('#test-table').DataTable({

            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{route('test.index')}}",
            "columns": [
                {"data": "values1"},
                {"data": "values2"},

            ],


        });
 $('.filter-select').change(function () {

            var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
             }).toArray().join("|");

            table.column($(this).data('column'))
                 .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
                .draw();
        });
```

I have tried to modify joining of values and removing regex option from `.search` but its not quite working and I also don't really like this solution.

```
var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
            return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
         }).toArray().join(' OR '+($(this).data('column_name')));

table.column($(this).data('column'))
                 .search(vals.length > 0 ? vals : '')
                .draw();
```

I am using Laravel 8, SQL Server 2019 and JQuery datatables 1.12.1.
Any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `REGEXP` so what exactly are you trying to do? You are just going to have to manage with `LIKE`

Comment: disable regex, and use `LIKE` operator with `%` to wildcard the search. example, search term starts with `Ruso` it would be `LIKE 'Ruso%'` any value starts with `Ruso` would be included in the search.